# How SQL Server uses its Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I work in a bank. We have a table with 4 billion records and I created a non-clustered index for three columns: `ACNO, HisDate, BranchNo`.

My question is, if run this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.LastBalance 
WHERE HisDate = '20170813' 
  AND BranchNo = '0512'
```

Does SQL Server use that index or not?

I should use three columns in the `WHERE` clause until SQL Server uses the index?
Is column sequence important in `WHERE` cluase?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the index is really created in this manner:

```
CREATE INDEX (name) ON dbo.YourTable(ACNO, HisDate, BranchNo)
```

then it *might* be used, if:

- you use **all** three of these columns in a `WHERE` clause
- if you use just `ACNO` and `HisDate`
- if you use just `ACNO`

but it will ***NEVER*** be used in your case - it can *only* be used if you specify the **n left-most** columns in the index (this applies to *all* compound indices - indices that use more than one column).

You are only using `HisDate` and `BranchNo` - but you're not specifying `ACNO`, so this index is **useless** and will never ever be used. You should have an index on `(HisDate, BranchNo)` - *that* would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.  Oracle has a "skip-scan" operation on its indexes.  I don't think SQL Server implements such a thing.

The best index for the query would have the `HisDate` and `BranchNo` as the first two columns in the index (in either order).